# Python for loop list values

Tags: python

This is what i got so far, I have tried so many way the for loop, cannot assign the list values to questions and if correct only add correct answer.

```
my_list = [100, 200, 300]
x = 0


def quest():
    question = input('What color are apples?\n(a) red\n(b) blue\n(c) yellow\n')
    if question != 'a':
        print('Not correct try again')

    question = input('What color are blueberries?\n(a) red\n(b) blue\n(c) yellow\n')
    if question != 'b':
        print('Not correct try again')

    question = input('What color are watermelon?\n(a) green\n(b) blue\n(c) yellow\n')
    if question != 'b':
        print('Not correct try again')


quest()
```

Comment: " I have tried so many way the for loop" We can't tell you what's wrong with the things you tried, unless you show us the things you tried. There is no for loop in the code you posted, and I can't understand what you want the code to do. I especially have no idea what "assign the list values to questions" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to organize your test using a for loop

**Code**

```
def quest():
  points = [100, 200, 300]

  # Orgainize questions as list of strings
  questions = [
    'What color are apples?\n(a) red\n(b) blue\n(c) yellow\n',
    'What color are blueberries?\n(a) red\n(b) blue\n(c) yellow\n',
    'What color are watermelon?\n(a) green\n(b) blue\n(c) yellow\n']

  # Organize answer as list of letters
  answers = ['a', 'b', 'a']

  score = 0
  for i in range(len(questions)):
    if input(questions[i]) != answers[i]:
      print('Sorry, not correct')
    else:
      score += points[i]

  return score

print(f'Your score is: {quest()}')
```

**Concise Version**

```
def quest():
  points = [100, 200, 300]

  # Orgainize questions as list of strings
  questions = [
    'What color are apples?\n(a) red\n(b) blue\n(c) yellow\n',
    'What color are blueberries?\n(a) red\n(b) blue\n(c) yellow\n',
    'What color are watermelon?\n(a) green\n(b) blue\n(c) yellow\n']

  # Organize answer as list of letters
  answers = ['a', 'b', 'a']

  return sum((p for q,a,p in zip(questions, answers, points) if input(q) == a))

print(f'Your score is: {quest()}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been cracking my head over this for 10 hours.

Comment: @pystudent--glad to help.  Don't worry, keep practicing and what use to take hours will become minutes.

Comment: @pystudent--added a more concise version that is functionally equivalent to the first as an alternative.  This uses the zip function which is a popular method for incrementing over several lists in parallel.